# Display the Total price of the number of products selected by its unit price in textbox

Tags: excel, vba

I need my VBA user form to display the total price of the number of products selected.

[image]

Sorry guys this is my first time asking a question on SO, I am trying to build the userform as shown above.

I achieve almost everything except this TextBox total(Accessories total). Before I click the confirm booking button, if I add values in Accessories frame is it possible to update the total in TextBox (Accessories total)?

Below is my peace of code

```
'Column F(Racket Count) Enter No of rackets Taken

If IsNumeric(RacketCount) Then

Sheets("DataEntry").Range("S.No").Offset(RowCountOffset, 5) = CInt(RacketCount)

Else

MsgBox "Please enter valid Number"

End If

'Column G(Shuttle Count) Enter No of Shuttle's Taken

If IsNumeric(ShuttleCount) Then

Sheets("DataEntry").Range("S.No").Offset(RowCountOffset, 6) = CInt(ShuttleCount)

Else

MsgBox "Please enter valid Number"

End If

'Column H(Shoes Count) Enter No of Shoe's Taken

If IsNumeric(ShoesCount) Then

Sheets("DataEntry").Range("S.No").Offset(RowCountOffset, 7) = CInt(ShoesCount)

Else

MsgBox "Please enter valid Number"

End If

'Column I(Socks Count) Enter No of Sock's Taken

If IsNumeric(SocksCount) Then

Sheets("DataEntry").Range("S.No").Offset(RowCountOffset, 8) = CInt(SocksCount)

Else

MsgBox "Please enter valid Number"

End If


'Column J(Advance) Advance ON/OFF

If AdvanceOnOff = True Then

Sheets("DataEntry").Range("S.No").Offset(RowCountOffset, 9) = "yes"

Else

Sheets("DataEntry").Range("S.No").Offset(RowCountOffset, 9) = "No"

End If


'Column K(Racket Total *50) Total Amt for Rackest taken

Dim RacketsTotal As Integer

RacketsTotal = CInt(RacketCount) * Sheets("Inventory").Range("c2")

Sheets("DataEntry").Range("S.No").Offset(RowCountOffset, 10) = RacketsTotal

'Column L(Shuttle total* 160) Total Amt for Shuttle's taken

Dim ShuttleTotal As Integer

ShuttleTotal = CInt(ShuttleCount) * Sheets("Inventory").Range("c3")

Sheets("DataEntry").Range("S.No").Offset(RowCountOffset, 11) = ShuttleTotal

'Column M(Shoes Total * 50) Total Amt for Shoes's taken

Dim ShoesTotal As Integer

ShoesTotal = CInt(ShoesCount) * Sheets("Inventory").Range("c4")

Sheets("DataEntry").Range("S.No").Offset(RowCountOffset, 12) = ShoesTotal

'Column N(Socks Total * 30) Total Amt for Socks's taken

Dim SocksTotal As Integer

SocksTotal = CInt(SocksCount) * Sheets("Inventory").Range("c5")

Sheets("DataEntry").Range("S.No").Offset(RowCountOffset, 13) = SocksTotal

'Column O(Accessories Total) Total Accessories Amt

Dim AccTol As Long

AccTol = RacketsTotal + ShuttleTotal + ShoesTotal + SocksTotal

Sheets("DataEntry").Range("S.No").Offset(RowCountOffset, 14) = AccTol

AccessoriesTotalDisplay.Value = AccTol


Unload CourtBooking

MsgBox "Booking Entered Sucessfully"

End Sub
```

Comment: 1) SO is not a code writing service, you have to make your own attempt and post your code. 2) Without data, how are we supposed to help you? 3) You can edit the value in the `TextBox` via its `Value` property.

Comment: hi @RaymondWu i edit my question please let me know if its better to understand.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to make a function that counts the total accessories from the 4 `Textbox` and then assign `AccessoriesTotalDisplay.Value` to the function by using `AccessoriesTotalDisplay.Value = GetTotalAccessories`.

To make the calculation "real-time", you can insert that line into the 4 accessories' `Change` event as the code below shows:

```
Function GetTotalAccessories() As Long
    
    Dim totalRacket As Long
    Dim totalShuttle As Long
    Dim totalShoes As Long
    Dim totalSocks As Long
    
    If IsNumeric(RacketsCount) Then
        totalRacket = CLng(RacketsCount.Value)
    Else
        totalRacket = 0
    End If
    
    If IsNumeric(ShuttleCount) Then
        totalShuttle = CLng(ShuttleCount.Value)
    Else
        totalShuttle = 0
    End If
    
    If IsNumeric(ShoesCount) Then
        totalShoes = CLng(ShoesCount.Value)
    Else
        totalShoes = 0
    End If
    
    If IsNumeric(SocksCount) Then
        totalSocks = CLng(SocksCount.Value)
    Else
        totalSocks = 0
    End If
    
    Dim AccTol As Long
    AccTol = totalRacket + totalShuttle + totalShoes + totalSocks
        
    GetTotalAccessories = AccTol
End Function

Private Sub RacketsCount_Change()
    AccessoriesTotalDisplay.Value = GetTotalAccessories
End Sub

Private Sub ShoesCount_Change()
    AccessoriesTotalDisplay.Value = GetTotalAccessories
End Sub

Private Sub ShuttleCount_Change()
    AccessoriesTotalDisplay.Value = GetTotalAccessories
End Sub

Private Sub SocksCount_Change()
    AccessoriesTotalDisplay.Value = GetTotalAccessories
End Sub
```